# jQuery - change CSS of span inside a clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, expand

I have a table:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
        Click me! 
        <span class="expand" style="display: none;">Hidden text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row">
    <td>
        Click me! 
        <span class="expand" style="display: none;">Hidden text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The idea being that each row can be clicked, and clicking the row will reveal the hidden span in the cell. Here's the jQuery I've been trying:

```
$("#row").click(function () {
    $(this).class(".expand").style = "";
});
```

I am using $(this) because there are many `spans` of the same class and I only want to expand the span within the clicked row.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: Use the css method in the answers below.  Also, isn't a class supposed to be `".row"` instead of `"#row"`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".row").click(function () {
    $(this).find("span.expand").show(); //Shows specific span for each row
});
```

Note: `#row` is wrong since `row` is a class. Use `.row`

Answer (score 3):

This should sort you out :

jQuery:

```
$('.row').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').show();
});
```

*Note that each row has a class of 'row' so the element is '.row' not '#row' (which would refer to an ID of 'row')

Answer (score 2):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set style via jQuery

```
$(".row").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".expand").css('color','red');
    //to show use
    $(this).find(".expand").show();
});
```

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Also read

[css with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/)

Comment: #row references an ID not a class

Comment: @PatDobson corrected ty for letting me know that .i didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

Use this code...

```
$('.row').click(function(){      // row is class not id
     $(this).find('span').show();
});
```

If you want to toggle the display (show when hidden and hide when shown) then use..

```
$('.row').click(function(){      // row is class not id
     $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```